# MySQl - Import Multiple .sql Tables

Tags: mysql, import, sqlyog

How do i import backup of individual tables (.sql files). I want to use a Db name,ip (mysql machine ip), user, pwd to import all .sql files. My MySQL is on a windows machine

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

From cmd, cd location - all my individual .sql files are here

for /r %%i in (*) do mysql --user=username --host=ip --port=portnumber --password=pwd -B DbName< %%i

This worked good for me